# Searching a text file and counting how many times certain phrases appear in Octave

Tags: octave

I'm trying to write a script in Octave to scan a .bsg file, a file used for the game "Besiege" to store creations, and counts how many of each block there is.  It should then calculate a total score with a predetermined cost for each block.  .bsg files are in xml format and can be opened with text editors.

Here's a small section of what it might be scanning:

```
<Blocks>
        <Block id="0" guid="fdc9868c-e86d-48eb-b8e1-03eeb45d49fa">
            <Transform>
                <Position x="0.875" y="0.9999993" z="-9" />
                <Rotation x="-4.371139E-08" y="1" z="4.371139E-08" w="1.910685E-15" />
                <Scale x="1" y="1" z="1" />
            </Transform>
            <Data />
        </Block>
        <Block id="35" guid="02c86448-e87e-4d8f-92c5-b1c923b7f538">
            <Transform>
                <Position x="0.875" y="-0.5000007" z="0" />
                <Rotation x="-0.707107" y="-6.181725E-08" z="-6.181723E-08" w="0.7071066" />
                <Scale x="5.000033" y="12" z="1.000004" />
            </Transform>
            <Data>
                <Single key="bmt-mass">100</Single>
                <Boolean key="bmt-scale">True</Boolean>
                <Single key="bmt-x-scale">5</Single>
                <Single key="bmt-y-scale">12</Single>
                <Single key="bmt-z-scale">1</Single>
            </Data>
        </Block>
```

And so my problem is that I've no idea how to go about this, as I'm new to coding.  I've looked up load, scan, textread, and I can't seem to get anything to work with my file.

Comment: Your question lacks some details. 1) What is precisely a "block" for you? 2) In your sample, what is the result you are expecting? 3) why do you want/need to do that in Octave?

Comment: @PierU: Agreed with your 1) and 2). For 3), it's his business, not ours ;-)

Comment: @S.Gougeon Yes and no. The OP says they are new to coding, so maybe not aware the other tools may be more suited for the task, depending also on the points 1 and 2...

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do is to parse a XML document. For this task you don’t have to read file manually (using scan, textread, etc...). You need a library that will do it for you.

Unfortunately, Octave isn’t a good choice for this kind of task. I would suggest to solve this task with a modern script language like Python. It’ll be much easier and efficient.

But if you have to solve it using the Octave, here some tips for you to get started (I assume you’re using a Linux OS):

1. install **liboctave-dev** package (if you don’t have it in the system), run this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install liboctave-dev
```

2. download **Octave IO** package: https://octave.sourceforge.io/io/
3. install package (run this command from the Octave console, ‘**install io-2.6.4.tar.gz**’ should be in a current directory):

```
pkg install io-2.6.4.tar.gz
```

4. download **The Apache Xerces** binaries from here: https://xerces.apache.org/mirrors.cgi#binary
   Direct URL for the latest version right now is: https://dlcdn.apache.org//xerces/j/binaries/Xerces-J-bin.2.12.2.tar.gz

And extract the archive (it’ll be extracted in a directory named ‘**xerces-2_12_2**’)

5. Put this directory in the project’s directory (where you store your *.m files)
6. Create a new *.m file and paste this:

```
pkg load io

javaaddpath ("./xerces-2_12_2/xercesImpl.jar");
javaaddpath ("./xerces-2_12_2/xml-apis.jar");

clc
clear

xmlTree = xmlread("test.xml")
```

7. Now run the script. Assuming that you have a “test.xml” file in a project directory, and it is a correct XML file, you should get this output in the Octave’s console:

```
xmlTree =

<Java object: org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl>
```

That means that xmlread method works.

From now on, you could parse a XML tree using Xerces’ API methods. See documentation for more info: https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xerces/dom/package-tree.html

One approach might be using the **xml2struct** script from here: https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518-xml2struct

But it won’t work “as is” on the Octave (because Octave isn’t fully compatible with Matlab). You’ll need to modify it. One particular part would be with lines like this one:

```
theAttributes = getAttributes(theNode); % Matlab syntax
```

You’ll have to rewrite it to the Octave syntax - like this:

```
theAttributes = theNode.getAttributes; % Octave syntax
```

Some other modification might be required, too.

After that you will be able to retrieve data you care about from the struct and manipulate with it (count “blocks” or whatever you need to do).